# How can I keep the hover effect like a rating bar css code?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Click the code and see it. I could do all the hover effect I want except one that I could not keep the green highlight after user click the radio button. Like most star rating code, if the user select the third radio button, the first three items should be green. I know I should use `> ~`, `:checked` and `:not(:checked)`,  I had tried a lot but fail, appreciate your help!

```css
#rating_bar{
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    margin: 4px 175px !important;    
    display:inline-block;
    display:inline;
}

#rating_bar > label:before{
     content:'0';
     color: #c7c5c5;
     cursor:pointer;
     font-size:3em;
}

#rating_bar:hover > label:before {
    color: #4bce32;
}
#rating_bar > label:hover ~ label:before {
    color: #c7c5c5;
}
#rating_bar >input :checked ~ label:before {
    color: #c7c5c5;
}
```

```html
<div id="rating_bar">

   <input type="radio" id="rate_1" name="rating_f" value="1" /><label for="rate_1" title="Super effecitive!"></label>
   <input type="radio" id="rate_2" name="rating_f" value="1" /><label for="rate_2" title="Pretty effective!"></label>
   <input type="radio" id="rate_3" name="rating_f" value="3" /><label for="rate_3" title="Effective!"></label>
   <input type="radio" id="rate_4" name="rating_f" value="4" /><label for="rate_4" title="Kinda effective!"></label>
   <input type="radio" id="rate_5" name="rating_f" value="5" /><label for="rate_5" title="Not effective!"></label>

</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at this one http://everythingfrontend.com/posts/star-rating-input-pure-css.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no previous siblings selector in CSS. The solution is reversing the order of the characters, make it acts like next siblings.

```css
#rating_bar {
    display:inline;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: rtl;
}
#rating_bar > input {
    display: none;
}
#rating_bar > label[title] {
    direction: ltr;
}
#rating_bar > label:before {
    content:'★';
    color: #c7c5c5;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#rating_bar > label:hover:before,
#rating_bar > label:hover ~ label:before,
#rating_bar > input:checked ~ label:before {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="rating_bar">
    <input type="radio" id="rate_5" name="rating_f" value="5" />
    <label for="rate_5" title="Not effective!"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="rate_4" name="rating_f" value="4" />
    <label for="rate_4" title="Kinda effective!"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="rate_3" name="rating_f" value="3" />
    <label for="rate_3" title="Effective!"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="rate_2" name="rating_f" value="2" />
    <label for="rate_2" title="Pretty effective!"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="rate_1" name="rating_f" value="1" />
    <label for="rate_1" title="Super effecitive!"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This sort of thing can be difficult because of the fact that `~` only looks at siblings after the element and not before.  You were able to get around this with the `hover` but likely can't with the `:checked`.

In this case though, there is a workaround.  You can use `float: right` to visually reverse the order of the elements while maintaining their order within the DOM.  So then you just reverse the order of the elements in your markup.  Then, using `~` will affect elements which are visually preceding because they are actually later in the dom.

```css
#rating_bar {
    width:130px;
    height:30px;
    margin: 4px 175px !important;
    display:inline-block;
}
#rating_bar > label {
    float: right;
}
#rating_bar > input {
    display: none;
}
#rating_bar > label:before {
    content:'0';
    color: #c7c5c5;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:3em;
}
#rating_bar > label:hover:before {
    color: #4bce32;
}
#rating_bar > label:hover ~ label:before {
    color: #4bce32;
}
#rating_bar > input:checked ~ label:before {
    color: #4bce32;
}
```

```html
<div id="rating_bar">
    <input type="radio" id="rate_5" name="rating_f" value="5" />
    <label for="rate_5" title="Not effective!"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="rate_4" name="rating_f" value="4" />
    <label for="rate_4" title="Kinda effective!"></label>    
    <input type="radio" id="rate_3" name="rating_f" value="3" />
    <label for="rate_3" title="Effective!"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="rate_2" name="rating_f" value="1" />
    <label for="rate_2" title="Pretty effective!"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="rate_1" name="rating_f" value="1" />
    <label for="rate_1" title="Super effecitive!"></label>
</div>
```

A similar approach would also be possible using `flex` to re-order the elements visually.

http://jsfiddle.net/5h9n72dt/1/

Comment: I would suggest also making your hover and selected colors slightly different to distinguish:  http://jsfiddle.net/5h9n72dt/2/